# How can I move game objects using keyboard in the Unity scene editor?

Tags: unity

I know I can click on the "move" button

[image: move button in the UI]

and use my mouse to drag the object around. How can I do the same using my keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Q/W/E/R/T to trigger those buttons, W being "move", E "rotate" and R "scale". This is faster than clicking the buttons in my opinion.

However, there is unfortunately no key for "grabbing and moving" an object, like for example blender has.

Answer (score 2):

There is no keyboard shortcuts for moving a selected object around (afaik). What I like to do is change the location on each axis by selecting the gameobject in question and moving it using the inspector; If you mouse over the axis you are working with (for instance: X), you can 'drag' it right or left to increase and decrease that value. This might be a good alternative.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just made a Unity editor script to accomplish exactly what you are looking for. Check it out at this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/dvddarias/dd4206dec54a3f48aa536126de2594b0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my copy of unity to hand right now to try it out, but I couldn't find any way to move gameobjects using the keyboard. However, I did find [this page full of keyboard shortcuts](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2011/08/24/unity-hotkeys-keyboard-shortcuts-in-unity/). Also, if the issue was not having enough precision with the mouse, you can always use [snapping](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PositioningGameObjects.html) to make sure that the vertices and objects align properly.